# Draw array of points with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Why in this program four points drawn by glVertex3f rendered in pointed positions, but instead of four array points rendered only one in the center of the window?

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct point3 {
    GLfloat x, y, z;
};

vector<point3> Vertices(4);

void display(void)
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLuint abuffer;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &abuffer);
    glBindVertexArray(abuffer);
    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    Vertices = {{0.3f, 0.3f, 0.5f}, {0.6f, 0.6f, 0.5f}, {0.6f, 0.3f, 0.5f}, {0.3f, 0.6f, 0.5f}};
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertices[0]), &Vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &Vertices[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, Vertices.size());
    glFlush();
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.5f);
    glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.5f);
    glEnd();    
    glFlush();
} 

void init (void)
{
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

} 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("simple OpenGL example");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << endl;
    }
    cout << "Status: Using GLEW" << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << endl;    
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Why are you generating a vertex array and buffer object *every frame* you render? That's one-time setup work, not every frame work.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas, i tried to make it work and did many things, sure it must be in separate function.

Comment: @NicolBolas good point but this might be just a minified example for SO.

Comment: Okay, problem was in this line ''glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, NULL);'' - last parameter

Answer (score 2):

You haven't enabled the attribute to actually use the array. You do that by:

- (OpenGL 2) `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` (or `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`, etc)
- (OpenGL 3) `glEnableVertexArray(attributeId)`

Without that, what you point to with `glVertexPointer` (GL2) or `glVertexAttribPointer` (GL3) won't be actually used.

Comment: if i put glEnableClientState right before glVertexPointer and glDisableClientState right after glDrawArrays, it doesnt work anyway. may you can show code snippet?